# Puede 7z borrar los ficheros 7z una vez extraidos?

Tags: zip

tengo un programa que a traves de la orden Shell y 7za descomprimen un fichero que inmediatamente después de descomprimirse debe ser borrado.

El programa principal no puede esperar a la finalización de la descompresión para borrar el fichero comprimido por lo que es el programa descompresor el que debe hacerlo, pero en la documentación del 7z no encuentro nada.

Comment: ¿Y cómo extraes los archivos del 7z? ¿Nos muestras cómo lo haces desde el terminal? ¿Qué sistema operativo utilizas? ¿Puedes utilizar un script propio para resolver tal problema?

Comment: Un programa revisa automaticamente unos directorios donde otros programas dejan ficheros 7z. Según el nombre de los 7z, se descomprimen en otros directorios y una vez hecho deben ser eliminados.

Comment: Se hace a través de la orden Shell("7za e *.7z -aoa -y"). Y funciona desde XP a W10.

Comment: ¿Usando qué lenguaje de programación?

Comment: Con que funcione desde la linea de comandos es suficiente.

Comment: Algo como.. `Shell("7za e *.7z -aoa -y IF /I "%ERRORLEVEL%" EQU "0" DEL /F <NombreArchivo>")` debería funcionar.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia pero el problema sigue siendo el mismo, la segunda linea del script termina antes que la primera (intenta borrar el 7z antes de haberlo descomprimido y ni lo descomprime ni lo borra).

Comment: Si tarda 5 o 6 segundos en descomprimir, sólo el descompresor sabe cuando ha acabado y sólo él puede borrar el original de una manera "elegante". Cualquier otra opción implica que el proceso principal -u otro adicional- se quede esperando a que el descompresor termine y eso no es admisible por los efectos colaterales que puede haber con otros ficheros que estén llegando o se estén descomprimiendo. La única solución es que el descompresor se encargue y no entiendo que el 7z no tenga esa opción.

Answer (score 0):

Pues al final he prescindido de 7z y me he pasado al zip. 
A partir de las publicaciones de Vladimir Vissoultchev (https://github.com/wqweto/) he copiado su código y lo he incluido directamente en mi proyecto. El zip no es tan eficiente como el 7z, pero ahora controlo con precisión el funcionamiento del programa.